# Postgresql to_number() function format

Tags: sql, postgresql, type-conversion, sqldatatypes

I want to use postgresql `to_number(numberString, format_mask)`. My numberString may contain leading zeros (I don't know the actual length of these zeros and the numberString in total). I want to trim these zeros and get the value as number.

I've read about this function [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/to_number.php) and currently using the format:

```
select to_number('00005469', '9999999999')
```

But if the length of '9's is less than the length of the numberString then I can't get the correct number. How can I make this work without writing a long list of '9' in format_mask?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need `to_number()` for this. Just cast the string to an integer:

```
select '00005469'::integer;
```

or using standard SQL:

```
select cast('00005469' as integer);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more safe if your column has decimals or not, use

```
 select  NULLIF('00005469', '')::decimal
```

This `select '00005469'::integer;` will not work if there are decimals

Answer (score -1):

use like this it is simple:

`to_number(to_char(yournumber, '99'),'99')`

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the accepted and upvoted answer this question already has. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).