# I am looking to convert a select statement from oracle to postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

```sql
select max(to_number(ltrim(aefo_number,'VE')))
from   exemption
where  aefo_number like 'E%'
or     aefo_number like 'V%'
```

I am getting  Function to_number(text) does not exist error for the above select statement and I am unable to convert it.

If anyone know the syntax for the select statement please let me know

Comment: What error? Does the error say that a specific function doesn't exist ? Shouldn't you try to find the equivalent?

Comment: not sure ltrim works that way in postgresql you may have to use case expression to evaluate and replace or regular expressions.

Comment: Function to_number(text) does not exist

Comment: What version of postgres?  Maybe you need to just cast to number... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294045/postgresql-to-number-function-format  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html shows the formatting is needed on to_number(text,text)

Comment: Did you check the manual and functions? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Oracle, Postgres' `to_number()` function always needs a format mask. So you would need something like `to_number(ltrim(aefo_number,'VE'), '99999999999')`

If you don't want to (or can't) specify a format mask, you could cast the value to a `numeric` oder `integer`:

```
select max(ltrim(aefo_number,'VE')::integer)
from   exemption
where  aefo_number like 'E%'
or     aefo_number like 'V%'
```

Comment: Syntax error is showing mr.horse for 2nd one and 1st method one also not working

Comment: @Harish: then you are running a different statement. The code in my answer [certainly works](https://dbfiddle.uk/CpYMp5-u)

Answer (score 0):

If `V` and `E` are only the first character then you can use:

```sql
select MAX(SUBSTR(aefo_number,2)::integer)
from   exemption
where  aefo_number like 'E%'
or     aefo_number like 'V%'
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DxocDPMA)

Comment: invalid input syntax for type integer is showing @ Mto for yours

Comment: @Harish Please look at the fiddle linked in my answer; it shows the code working in PostgreSQL without any syntax errors. Are you sure you are running the same code and that you are using PostgreSQL?